# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

I just updated my Xcode to version 10. and when i run my project and then it shows me the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::_List_node_base::unhook()", referenced from:
  std::list<Linphone::Conference::Participant, 
std::allocator<Linphone::Conference::Participant> 
>::remove(Linphone::Conference::Participant const&) in 
liblinphone.a(conference.cc.o)
"std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
  Linphone::Conference::addParticipant(_LinphoneCall*) in 
liblinphone.a(conference.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: find an answer for above?